# Can't spawnUri() from a dart:io app to a dart:html app?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is this possible?  That is to say, I tried it and it didn't work.  But in theory it should be possible shouldn't it?  I'm only passing messages back and forth, isolated memory space, etc.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

main(){
  final sp = spawnUri('path/to/dart_html_app.dart');
}
```

throws:

```
IsolateSpawnException: 'Do not know how to load 'dart:html'
```

Comment: If the code above is running in the server-side VM, then it doesn't have access to dart:html (afik).  I can imagine, however, a scenario using websockets, where a previously connected browser could use a some proxy object to "spawn" a client-side dart isolate.  Is this the type of scenario you envisage?

Comment: I also can't see this working directly. Not to spawn simply because specifically spawning says to me "in this vm launch another isolate with code retrieved from x". That said I could see a time when a Websocket is used to trigger the creation of an isolate in another vm instance (ie dartium) and then returning a send port to that isolate. Just not a specific spawning of the isolate itself.

Comment: spawnUri() says to you "spawn in this VM"?  It doesn't to me.  it says spawn from a uri location, anywhere.

Comment: Anywhere? But where? Isolates are in-process only, at least for now, and I'd guess that this won't change for quite some time.

Comment: I think spawnUri() is just a bad name. I think of it as similar to an import statement, but it loads the library into a new isolate and calls main(). I think that it might be better as spawnLibrary(), though I'm not sure that "library" indicates that main() will be called.

Answer (score 2):

As someone already stated, you can't import `dart:html` in the VM (at least at this point). Your solution would be to split the app into two libraries, where the one you want to spawn does not use `dart:html`.

What are you actually trying to do? If you think you could have the browser and VM talk via isolates, that's not going to work. Isolates use a thread pool in the VM and Web Workers on the browser if they are available.

If you just want "load the code from this URI  and execute it just like any code in a new isolate", then that's certainly possible -- why not? You just have to refactor your code base so that you don't import `dart:html` except only when you really need it.